# Failure of the second derivative test

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

We had to examine what kind of point is $(0,0)$, for the function $$f(x,y)=2(x − y)^
2 − x^
4 − y^
4.$$

(The given answer is *saddle point*)

Both the partial derivatives are zero at $(0,0)$, however, the Hessian too, is zero for $(0,0)$, which means that second derivative test is inconclusive.

**How then , can we come to the conclusion that $(0,0)$ is a saddle point?**

I tried examining the sign of the first derivatives (Like we used to do for one variable functions), but I cant seem to think of a procedure that will do the job correctly, the extra variable is causing a bit of a problem...

Comment: Show that $f $ takes both positive and negative values in small neighborhoods around $(0, 0)$, so this point is a saddle point of $f$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do it by hand.  We have $f(0,0) = 0$, so we mush show on some lines through $(0,0)$,  $f$ is positive in both directions, and on other lines it is negative in both directions.

For small $t$ we have
$$
f(t,0) = 2t^2-t^4 \sim 2t^2 > 0
$$
on both sides of $(0,0)$, and for small $t$ we have
$$
f(t,t) = -2t^4 < 0
$$
on both sides of $(0,0)$.